# Control edge with neato layout with processmapR

Tags: r, graph, graphviz, diagrammer, neato

I'm using the bupaR process mining suite and processmapR to plot my log as a process map but when I try to set a custom position (which force the graph to use a neato layout) the edge become almost staight and the edge value hard to read:

Default graph with no custom position:
[image]
With custom position:
[image]

I tried to use

```
positions <- data.frame(act = c("node1","node2","node 3","node 4","node 5","Start", "End"),
                        y = c(5,4,3,2,1,6,0),
                        x = c(1,2,3,4,5,0,6),
                        stringsAsFactors = F)
graph = process_map(log, fixed_node_pos = positions, render = F)
map = add_global_graph_attrs(graph,
                             attr = "splines",
                             value = "true", 
                             attr_type = "graph")
render_graph(map)
```

But I could not find any attribute to change the way edge are displayed, like adding more curve to them

How can I fix this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
map = add_global_graph_attrs(graph,
                             attr = "splines",
                             value = "curved", 
                             attr_type = "graph")
```